# Inserting the data in to the local server from android Application

Tags: android

I have developed an application which uses GCM notifications, i have successfully registered the device with GCM, and retrieved regId, now i want to send this ID to my server.

i am using this code to send the regId:

```
package com.example.gcm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class ShareExternalServer {

    public String shareRegIdWithAppServer(final Context context,
            final String regId) {

        String result = "";
        Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        paramsMap.put("regId", regId);
        try {
            URL serverUrl = null;
            try {
                serverUrl = new URL(Config.APP_SERVER_URL);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("AppUtil", "URL Connection Error: "
                        + Config.APP_SERVER_URL, e);
                result = "Invalid URL: " + Config.APP_SERVER_URL;
            }

            StringBuilder postBody = new StringBuilder();
            Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = paramsMap.entrySet()
                    .iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
                postBody.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                        .append(param.getValue());
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    postBody.append('&');
                }
            }
            String body = postBody.toString();
            byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = null;
            try {
                httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();
                httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
                httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
                httpCon.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
                httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                OutputStream out = httpCon.getOutputStream();
                out.write(bytes);
                out.close();

                int status = httpCon.getResponseCode();
                if (status == 200) {
                    result = "RegId shared with Application Server. RegId: "
                            + regId;
                } else {
                    result = "Post  new  one1 Failure." + " Status: " + regId;
                }
            } finally {
                if (httpCon != null) {
                    httpCon.disconnect();
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = "Post Failure 33 . Error in sharing with App Server."+regId;
            Log.e("AppUtil", "Error in sharing with App Server: " + e);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which language are you using on your server side?

Comment: server i am using java @Alok Gupta

Comment: please update the question to explain what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: I need to insert the regId in to my local server@yazan

Comment: yes i got it, but what is wrong with the code above? does it reach server or not? does it reach but server not saving value? does it show exception? you need to tell what exactly the issue is

Comment: Post Failure  . Error in sharing with App Server This error i am getting while sharing the RegId to my local server

Comment: this is the custom error message you are using, add `e.printStacktrace()` in the `catch` block and post the logcat output, this will tell what is the exact issue, meanwhile is the value of `Config.APP_SERVER_URL` =`localhost` or `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: I am thinking shall we use the insert query  to insert the RegId into our server it will work out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107828/discussion-between-yazan-and-pandu-k).

Comment: static final String APP_SERVER_URL =
 "http://192.168.1.113:8080/GCM-App-Server/GCMNotification?shareRegId=1"; This is my appserver url

Comment: are you  using `shareRegId` as parameter name in server side? if yes then you are using a different one in client `paramsMap.put("regId", regId);` you are using regId, they should be the same.